# MEAN Stack - Angular can only Communicate through the domain name

Tags: node.js, angular, localhost, mean

I have setup a Mean stack on a Digital Ocean Droplet based on UBUNTU 18.
I am using Angular6 on nginx port 80, nodejs on port 3333 which I run on the same machine. I have also enabled CORS on nodejs. The angular application gets build as prod and copied to the server. I have enabled as described on digital ocean the private ip and i can successfully curl the api (nodejs) using localhost, the internal IP and 127.0.0.1

Now the problem: When I am calling the API from the angular6 anything but the domain name is giving me an Error -> Connection Refused, Unknown Error! Locally on my development PC everything is working as It should! I thought it might be a cors issue but I am able to access via IP the remote API from my development machine without any issues. What am I missing? I find it very odd to be able to access it through the domain name and not via the internal IP... 
Note that on the development PC angular is running as ng serve... the only difference is that the application is build as prod before uploading it to the remote server.

Comment: So angular doesn't work when you give it an internal ip?

Comment: No it returns :  Connection Refused, Unknown Error. I can curl it from within the server and get the response.

Comment: The Angular code runs out of your browser, not on the server. You cant access the internal ip from outside the private network.

Comment: Doh! You are absolutely right. My bad. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Awesome and np. I'll drop a proper answer below so we can mark this guy as resolved and help keep stackoverflow clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular cant access the private ip because the angular code runs off your browser and not the server. So unless your running the browser right on the server via vnc or something, your local machine cant access the private network (and thus the private ip).

Digital ocean probably recommend you set up a private ip so that you can put your database in the private network so its firewalled off.

Anyhoo, use the FQDN or the public ip in your angular code.